# "Saturday last"

Tags: expressions

In researching the date of my grandparents' marriage, I found a Sunday newspaper article which said that they were wed "Saturday last." Does that mean yesterday, which was the last Saturday, or does it mean yesterday, a week ago?

Comment: I don't have an ironclad answer to your question (hence the comment), but I imagine that if the wedding had taken place the day before the newspaper appeared, the report would have said that it happened "yesterday." That's how most people would express the idea in everyday English, anyway. It follows (to my mind) that "Saturday last" means, in this case,  "a week from yesterday"—that is, not "this [most recent] Saturday" (yesterday), but the last Saturday before this most recent one. Consider, too, that the report was probably written on Saturday ("yesterday") for publication Sunday ("today").

Comment: As it turns out, I found an article about the wedding in another newspaper online, which said that they were wed 8 days before the signal article on that Sunday; so, you are right on!

Comment: It should be noted that such terminology is very frequently ambiguous, and subject to variations due to regional practices and the context of the use.

Comment: I have frequently wondered at what point in the course of a week "next Saturday" becomes "this Saturday".

Answer (score 1):

If the article was dated the same as the date of publication (**the** Sunday) as it should be, it means the wedding took place the **previous day** which happens to be ***Saturday last***.

ODO:

> **[last](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/last)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **2** **Most recent in time; latest**.
>
> ‘last year’
>
> [POSTPOSITIVE] ‘your letter of *Sunday last*’

Comment: Nice try, but that is option #2. Sorry! Not to be smug, because that is why I posed the question; the more I thought about it, the more I vacillated!

Comment: @JoeBurch, nice to know that you found your answer. I did mention about it being relative to the date of the article (as opposed to the date of the newspaper itself). Were they different?

Comment: Not that I could tell.

Comment: @JoeBurch, I see. Back in those days, they probably _postdated_ articles with the date of planned publication. Perhaps it took several days for the articles to reach the press.

Answer (score 1):

'Saturday last' is a rapidly disappearing equivalent to 'last Saturday'. At the time of its writing it would have been in very common usage.

Since the published account does not use the more commonly expected 'Yesterday' (if the wedding did indeed take place the day before), this raises the possibility that the account was written either on the Saturday immediately prior to the report's Sunday publication, or in the few days before that.

Comment: See my comment above, for definitive day of the wedding. This marriage took place over 110 years ago, in Jan. 1906; so, you nailed it!!